# Flex Application with Intuit IPP

Tags: apache-flex, saas

anyone already tried to build a Flex App, which would be run as a Federated Application on the Intuit IPP?
From my understanding it is very easy to build a native Flex App which runs on the Intuit environment. They also allow the approach of "Federated Applications", which lets you host your app (they say written in any language) anywhere and you still can connect to the workplace.

I am looking for a starting point for this approach. Thx,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

I've create [two screencasts](http://www.jamesward.com/blog/2008/11/12/intuit-unites-flex-rias-and-the-cloud/) that show how to build applications on the IPP.

Comment: Hi James!
Thanks for the reference. I just watched the screencasts, and they are interesting in regards to using Quickbase.
However I would like to take my existing Flex App (which is based on the LAMP stack), which is not hosted at Intuit, and I still want to integrate it with the Intuit Workplace, using IDS.
According to IPP, this can be achieved by the "Federated Application" approach, I am looking for a starting point for this. Any ideas?

Thx,
Martin

Comment: Here are some other resources:
https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=69&threadid=12261
https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/Federatedapps

Answer (score 0):

Working sample SAML gateways for IPP federation can also be found here:

https://code.intuit.com/sf/projects/ipp_fed_auth

Answer (score 0):

Should anyone come across this post, please be aware that Native and Federated Applications are deprecated on the Intuit Partner Platform. The new programming model to integrate with QuicKBooks is called Intuit Anywhere